# Ethereum ECR721 Create JSON to upload to IPFS

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am learing about Ethereum Smart Contract, NFT and ECR721 tokens with external Metadata.
I know that you can updload a JSON file using IPFS and _setTokerURI to keep this URI.

My question is how to create that JSON File on the fly in the App.js and how to decode to send it to IPFS.

Could you guys give me some direction of what to google to leard this? Thanks :)

Comment: It depends, what do you want to store in said json file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pinata SDK to interact with IPFS https://github.com/PinataCloud/Pinata-SDK#pinjsontoipfs